# What's special about infinite squeezing in continuous-variable quantum information?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics

Quantum error correction for continuous-variable systems using linear optics only works for the especial case of infinite squeezing? what's especial about infinite squeezing? (For example this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/27850)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things to mention. First off, infinite squeezing isn't physical because it corresponds to the infinite energy limit... Yet, it is a limit case which can often provide valuable insight.

For continuous-variable quantum error correction to work, one needs a nonpositive Wigner function somewhere (either in an ancilla state or in a gate). This is because finitely-squeezed Gaussian wave functions in the continuous regime have fuzziness which is conducive to error aggregation (this fuzziness disappears for infinite squeezing but... see above). There exist CV QEC codes based on non-Gaussian pure states. See Gottesman, Kitaev, and Preskill, PRA 2001, and Menicucci, PRL 2014.

Comment: I am aware of the Gottesman, Kitaev, and Preskill paper. Could you please elaborate what you mean by fuzziness? and why a non-positive Wigner function is necessary? A reference or some mathematical equation would be appreciated!

Comment: The "fuzziness" term simply refers to the width of the Wigner fct which yields DeltaX and DeltaP in ortheogonal directions of phase space. For the need for non-Gaussian Wigner functions see: Lloyd and Braunstein PRL 1999 for CVQC and also Bartlett, Sanders, Braunstein, and Nemoto, PRL 2002 for exponential speedup in CVQC. See Eisert, Scheel, and Plenio, PRL 2002 for entanglement distillation. And see Niset, Fiurasek, and Cerf PRL 2009 for quantum error correction.